# C struct syntax issue

Tags: c, syntax

So i want to select all elements of a struct and initialize them to 0 in C

```
typdef struct s_coord
{
  int x;
  int y;
} t_coord;
```

So in order to initialize them i should go

```
   int main(void)
    {
     t_coord coord;
     coord.x = 0;
     coord.y = 0;
    }
```

so i have a struct with more than 10 variables is there any way to initialize them all at the same time
something like:

```
coord.* = 0;
```

or

```
coord = 0;
```

???

Edit: Thanks guys for the answers i found out bzero function also works

Comment: Yep ! On declaration , write t_coord coord = { 0 };

Comment: `t_coord coord; coord.x = 0; coord.y = 0;` is not *initialization*.  You're actually *assigning* values to the *uninitialized* `coord` structure.  For what you want to do, that's a critical difference - you can write `t_coord coord = { 0 };` as in @Gromph's comment, but you can't write `t_coord coord; coord = { 0 };` because the `{ 0 }` syntax only works for initialization.  (I'm ignoring compound literals here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On declaration (as said in comments) :

```
t_coord coord = {0};
```

After declaration, you can set the memory to zero like this :

```
memset(&coord, 0, sizeof(t_coord));
```